# How to make auto installer Plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, installation

I made my first Wordpress plugin and I would get that crease a datatable in worpress databases. I tried the next code buy I get nothing:

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'rating_install');
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'rating_uninstall');
function rating_install(){
//Funcion que genera la instalacion del plugin
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix."rating";
$create = "CRETA TABLE ".$table_name." "
        . "(id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, "
        . "url tinytext NOT NULL, "
        . "descripcion tinytext NOT NULL)"
        . "PRIMARY KEY ('id')";
require_once(ABSPATH."wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php");
dbDelta($create);
}

function rating_uninstall(){
    //Funcion que genera la desinstalacion del plugin
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpbd->prefix."rating";
    $drop = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ".$table_name;
    require_once(ABSPATH."wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php");
    dbDelta($drop);
}
```

This functions will be do something when we enable/disabled the plugin...buy isn't works.

And other question...how I made the same event when I install the plugin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
function rating_install(){
    //Funcion que genera la instalacion del plugin
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix."rating";
    $create = "CRETA TABLE ".$table_name." ( "
            . "id INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, "
            . "url TINYTEXT NOT NULL, "
            . "descripcion TINYTEXT NOT NULL ) ";    
    $wpdb->query($create);
    /*require_once(ABSPATH."wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php");
    dbDelta($create);*/
}

function rating_uninstall(){
    //Funcion que genera la desinstalacion del plugin
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix."rating";
    $drop = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ".$table_name;
    $wpdb->query($drop);
    /*require_once(ABSPATH."wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php");
    dbDelta($drop);*/
}
```

I wrote wrong the create sentence and ussing $wpdb->query($create) works!

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 0):

`$create = "CRETA TABLE ".$table_name." ( "`

should probably read:

`$create = "CREATE TABLE ".$table_name." ( "`

You really should use the dbDelta() function as WordPress will assist with future Table upgrades/edits. Otherwise you will have to manually handle the database upgrades. Not fun.

Your final code will read something like this:

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'rating_install');

function rating_install(){
//Funcion que genera la instalacion del plugin
global $wpdb;
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix .'rating';    
$create = 
      "CREATE TABLE ".$table_name." (
      `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `url` TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
      `descripcion` TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`));";
dbDelta($create);
}
```

Also when you uninstall the plugin you really should put all that into an uninstall.php file saved in your plugin directory. This is the *proper* way to uninstall a plugin:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_uninstall_hook

```
<?php
// uninstall.php

//if uninstall not called from WordPress exit
if ( !defined( 'WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN' ) ) 
    exit();

$option_name = 'any added option name';
delete_option( $option_name );

// For site options in multisite
delete_site_option( $option_name );

//drop a custom db table
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query( "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$wpbd->prefix}rating" );
```